# "split /\|/" breaks Perl syntax highlighting

Tags: regex, perl, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I code using Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu, with the Beautify and Perl extensions among others. An annoyance is that this bit of code,

`split /\|/`

breaks the highlighter.[image: syntax is broken between the two occurrences of the code]

I'm a bit lost about where to poke in vscode to fix the highlighting error.

This is a large codebase that uses that regex relatively frequently. While refactoring it all to centralize that code might be a good suggestion in theory, for the purpose of the question please assume I cannot change this code right now. I was aiming more at where to poke in the vscode/extension highlighter, or if it is an actual error.

Comment: You can try /\x7c/ or m{\x7c}

Comment: In cases like this, I find I can often "close" the syntax element the editor has mistakenly identified by putting something behind a comment. `split /\|/, $var; # /`

Comment: I have edited your question to add the [syntax-highlighting] tag, but it needs a peer to accept the edit. You may do it yourself. With the [perl] tag you are going to get suggestions regarding the code...

Comment: @JavierElices This is a bit of a Perl-specific issue -- this language construct routinely confuses syntax highlighters, and there are some standard practices for mitigating the issue.

Comment: @duskwuff, I am sure it is, but the additional tag cannot harm, both with the answer and with finding the question in the future, don't you think?

Comment: I think maybe you need multiple values for a form parameter instead of special syntax in a single value to represent multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the easiest and clearest thing to do that solved the problem was calling the function using parentheses.

```
@result = split(/\|/, $input);
```

displays correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Even if it didn't break syntax highlighting, leaning toothpicks are hardly readable. Better use something like:

```
split qr{\Q|}, ...
```

Comment: In this case, `m{…}` is more appropriate than `qr{…}`.

Comment: @duskwuff I am afraid you do not know what you do not know. What do you think `split m{...}, $xyz` does?

Comment: The exact same thing as `split /…/, $xyz`. They're synonymous. `qr{…}` is only needed when you need to treat the regexp as a value, e.g. to assign it to a variable, or pass it as an argument to a non-builtin function.

Comment: @duskwuff, If you're going to be explicit, `qr` is clearer since the intent is to create a regex, not perform a match.

Comment: @duskwuff "*need to treat the regexp as a value ... pass it as an argument to a non-builtin function*" ... Why the artificial distinction?